# struts2+xslt and making new html file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, struts2

Hi I am working with struts2 .Presently i have an Xml file from where we are reading our definitions .Many html files needed to be created and send to browser .Presently I am reading and putting it in new html .But the tranformer is not able to find the location of html file.It works fine when done in standalone application.

```
        //Here is my code for the method which will read from xml using xsl put the content in the html file which after execution need to be send to the browser
        public class List {
            public String execute (){
                try {
            TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            // String outputFileName = is.getFile(); 
             Source xslDoc = new StreamSource("src/catalog.xsl");
             Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource("src/catalog.xml");
             String outputFileName = "WebContent/catalog.html";
             OutputStream htmlFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
             Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
             transformer.transform(xmlDoc ,new StreamResult(htmlFile));
          } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return "success";
        }
//Here i want to display catalog.html which will be rendered by the execute method
//This is the structure of my struts.xml file
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
            "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
          <struts>
            <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
                value="false" />
            <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
          <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
                <action name="List" method="execute"
                    class="priteshtiwary.List">
                    <result name="success">catalog.html</result>
//Here now catalog.html should be called after execution
                </action>
                </package>
        </struts>
         ThankYou
```

Comment: You should not access files in such way.